# Discord bot to check if a minecraft server is online

Tags: discord, minecraft, nodejs-server

I was wondering if anyone knew of a discord bot that will send a message in a discord sever when a minecraft server is online and send a message when it goes back offline

I've done some googling and can't seem to find one that does what I want there are a couple that u have to manually type commands for and others that appear in the sidebar of discord I simply want one that will do it automatically is there one that exists like this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found any not that already did this, but you can do this pretty easily with the Discord API.

Here is a a script I found that send a message to the server : https://gist.github.com/ianklatzco/769d9e3a991dc2f443a2e105b0157117

You can adapt it to ping the server in a if statement to send if it is online or not
(This script is in python but the Discord api works in more languages)